# Customising Data Sheet View

Tags: list, custom, content-editor-web-part, datasheet, design

I'm using SharePoint 2007, with custom list.

I'm using Content Editor web part in order to design my list.

{In my list the row color determined through the item ststus. 
e.g: If the status equal to "NOT STARTED" the row color is red, 
if the row status is "COMPLETED" so the row color is green, etc..}

My question is: I succeeded to implement it **only** on a custom list in standard view.
Is it possible to implement it on **data sheet view**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Customisations to the Data Sheet View are not supported, as this is generated using the Microsoft Office Access Web Datasheet Component, which renders the grid using the same base engine as the data sheet view that Microsoft Access uses.

Comment: from your answer I understood that I can not design custom list in data-sheet-view. so... do you have any creative idea what can I do in order to implement some "look and feel" design on data-sheet-view? thanks! :)

Comment: The simple answer is no, as the datasheet view runs as an ActiveX control, not simple HTML, so there's no way to simply use jQuery or similar to colour the markup.

Comment: Could you create a multiline dataform web part with conditional formatting to show the data as desired?  The dataform web part would act "like" a datasheet and allow for editing.  There might be some issues to work around with postbacking.

Comment: Hi PirateEric! I do not have the design authorize, and I think that I could implement the dataform web part only with sharepoint design. **am I wrong here**?

Comment: You are correct, you can create and customise dataform web parts using SharePoint Designer.

Comment: @JamesLove: Apparently your answer is considered definitive enough to be copied by the MS chaps: [MSDN: Apply conditional formatting for datasheet view of a SP List](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010customization/thread/0708abc5-483e-4d18-93a2-4bb8f664fb25/)

Comment: Lol, someone got wind of my opinion of the MSDN Forums already it seems :P

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following css in Content editor webpart to change the look and feel different for Datasheet view of sharepoint

```
<style>
BODY {
    BACKGROUND: #d3d3d3
}
FORM#aspnetForm {
    BACKGROUND-COLOR: #fff

}</style>
```

or

```
form#aspnetForm{ 
background-color:#000; 
height: 100%; 
text-align: center; 
} 
body{ 
background-color:#FFF; 
text-align: center; 
} 
.ms-main{ 
margin:0 auto; 
width: 980px; 
background-color:#FFF; 
} 
#mainTable{ 
width: 100%; 
}
```